# Class variable is being squashed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, class-variables

I'm running into this strange issue that I don't understand based on how python imports work (I believe)

I have a class defined, and a decorator that populates a class variable (dictionary) with values.  The decorator is applied in other modules to functions so they are registered within the class.  This is working properly (I can break and see that the class variable is populated).  However, when I run the code that causes me to look up those functions (in the class variable) the class variable is an empty dictionary.

```
event_cog.py
class Events(commands.Cog):
       REACTION_HANDLERS = dict()

def handle_reaction(reaction_emoji):
    """
    allows you to register a function as a specific reaction handler for the embed representing an event
    """

    def inner(func):
        Events.REACTION_HANDLERS[reaction_emoji] = func
        return func

    return inner

import b.py
```

```
b.py
import event_cog
@event_cog.handle_reaction(emo(":white_check_mark:", use_aliases=True))
async def event_white_check_mark_handler(
    self, ctx, channel: TextChannel, member: discord.Member, message: Message
):
```

if I set a breakpoint within the decorator after the two executions I see

```
str(Events.REACTION_HANDLERS)
'{\'✅\': <function event_white_check_mark_handler at 0x0584FBB8>, \'❌\': <function event_x_handler at 0x05835D68>}'
```

At any point later when my code would want to access these functions though...

```
str(Events.REACTION_HANDLERS)
'{}'
```

Comment: I will say that in debugging.. It breaks twice on REACTION_HANDLERS = dict() line... once when going through event_cog.py, and as second time when b.py import event_cog so that it has access to the decorator...

Comment: Something takes place that you didn't show us. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please make a [mcve] that shows exactly how `b.py` is importing `event_cog.py`.

Comment: updated... it imports event_cog

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with circular imports, but I'm struggling to understand why it would not work.

Comment: so I could fix it by moving all the code in b.py into where I call "import b.py", this seems to just remove all the errors.  But I can't understand why this is the case.